# executeScalar keeps returning exception errors

Tags: .net

I am using the 'using' construct but when I load images rapidly in a loop, I get the following error:

ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

The strange part is that it happens at different times in the loop every time I run it.

I have searched my entire solution and there are no calls to Open() or Close() anywhere but in the following:

```
    public myMethod()
    {
        string conString;
        conString = "Server=(local);Database=myDB;Uid=appaccess;Pwd=xxxxxx";
        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

And then later in my code I call this method in a loop of imgIDs:

```
    public byte[] GetImageBitStream(int imgID)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetImageBitStream", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@imgID", imgID));
        Object picData = new Object();
        picData = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (picData == null)
        {
            picData = "";
        }
        return (byte[])picData;
    }
```

I don't know what to try next! This code used to work and recently stopped working when I switched to the 'using' format. But even if I switch back, it errors now.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you really want to open and close the sql connection around the use of the sqlcommand.  That would  return and fetch the connection from the connection pool, which resets the connection on each use, allows you to work against a clustered sql server (partially) and keeps you from having to implement dispose.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx, unless this is what you mean that you've switched to the 'using' model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an connection leak to me.

Try refactoring along the following lines:

```
string conString;
conString = "Server=(local);Database=myDB;Uid=appaccess;Pwd=xxxxxx";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
     con.Open();
     foreach (int id in imgIdCollection)
     {
         var img = GetImageBitStream(id,con)
     }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I had declared SqlConnection con as a static. Works better as private or public. :)

Comment: Yep it does.  You shouldn't really keep a connection in a field as it is a common source of connection leaks. You become dependent on the garbage collector cleaning up before the connection pool runs out. I would still recommend you follow the using (var x = new sqlconnection()) {..} pattern.